# How to read data based on nested property in firebase database?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I currently have a firebase database with the following structure:

```
SharedGroup
 groupid1
     group: "test"
     members
        lastname,firstname@gmail,com: true
 groupid2
     group: "test new"
     members
        last,name@gmail,com: true
 groupid3
     group: "Family"
     members
         lastname,firstname@gmail,com: true
         last,name@gmail,com: false
         nobody@gmail,com: false
 groupid4
     group: "Friends"
     members
         lastname,firstname@gmail,com: true
 groupid5
     group: "Others"
     members
         nobody@gmail,com: true
Users
 9ybmUqR0SzLFA3aZSLV42nPp1lj2
     email: "last,name@gmail,com"
 lNZx6z7PZOUGUY0H3rtbFCYzmO53
     email: "lastname,firstname@gmail,com"
```

I wanted to setup a read rule that will not allow a user to read the groupid if the SharedGroup if it is not a member (email set to true).  I have managed to set up a read rule as follows:

```js
"SharedGroup" : {
  "$group_id": {
  ".read": " data.child('members').child(root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child('email').val()).val() === true "
  }
}
```

How can I read all groupid associated with a particular member in javascript?  Using the simulator, I am getting a error when reading from SharedGroup since I don't have any rules at that level.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to query the real-time database for a subset of items if the user doesn't have access to all of them.

The good news is that there are two workarounds:

1. Set up a Cloud Function for Firebase that gets updates to SharedGroup/{groupId}/members/{memberEmail} and makes either an index or a copy of the group in a database location like Indexes/groups/{userId}/{groupId}.
2. Switch to Firestore.

Firestore is like the RTDB, but better in most ways -- and still in beta. You don't need access to every document in a collection to pull down the ones you have access to. Set your read rule to something like:
`allow read: if resource.data.members[request.auth.email]`

Make your query check for `members.email == true`. That *should* all work.

By the way, I'd generally suggest using userIds instead of email addresses if you can manage it.

One disadvantage of any of these approaches is that every member can see who every other member is. If you don't want that, you'll have to set up a GroupMembers collection, where each document is a (user, group) pair. This isn't conceptually tough, but the devil is in the details. You can see some of them in [a forum post I made](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/qSFX85_m_X0/EcteET8WBQAJ) about what I referred to as "access" objects.